# Highlite text using javascript that get value from form parameter

Tags: javascript

i try to highlite a text using javascript, but using the value from form variable.
I dunno why its not working...

Can some one point out a way out, please...
below the script of page that i save as test01.php

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  span.highlight{background:yellow; padding:3px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self" id="form1">
  <label for="search"></label>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
<table width="978" border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="962">
    The house the red hare</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
var s = document.querySelector('input[type="<?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>"]'),
    p = document.querySelector('p'),
    find = function(){
        var words = p.innerText.split(' '),
            i = words.length,
            word = '';

        while(--i) {
            word = words[i];
            if(word.toLowerCase() == s.value.toLowerCase()){
                words[i] = '<span class="highlight">' + word + "</span>";
            }
            else{

            }   
        }

        p.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
    }

s.addEventListener('keydown', find , false);
s.addEventListener('keyup', find , false);</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the text ? (p)

Comment: The text is "The house the red hare", just example i input word "house" and click submit it not highlite the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [Javascript text highlight jquery Plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html), add the plugin your website :

```
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    span.highlight{background:yellow; padding:3px;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="" method="post" name="form1" target="_self" id="form1">
    <label for="search"></label>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['search'])) ? $_POST['search'] : ''; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <table width="978" border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td width="962">
      The house the red hare</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $_POST['search'] ?>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  /*

  highlight v4

  Highlights arbitrary terms.

  <http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html>

  MIT license.

  Johann Burkard
  <http://johannburkard.de>
  <mailto:jb@eaio.com>

  */

  jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
   function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
    var skip = 0;
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
     var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
     if (pos >= 0) {
      var spannode = document.createElement('span');
      spannode.className = 'highlight';
      var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
      var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
      var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
      spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
      middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
      skip = 1;
     }
    }
    else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
     for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
      i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
     }
    }
    return skip;
   }
   return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
    innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
   }) : this;
  };

  jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
   return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
    this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
    with (this.parentNode) {
     replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
     normalize();
    }
   }).end();
  };

      var s = <?php echo (isset($_POST['search'])) ? '"' .$_POST['search']. '"' : '""'; ?>;
      var p = document.querySelector('p');
      $(p).highlight(s);

      $('#search').keydown(function() {
        var s = $('#search').val();
        $(p).highlight(s);
      })

  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5013/)

Comment: I try the code you give me but its not working...all the code goes to under javascript tag right?

Comment: No it goes on top of the script tag, you must define the hightlight function before using it ;), see the JSFiddle :)

Comment: i already check JSFiddle and follow the arrangement...add the missing "<p>" but still not working

Comment: I updated my post, i made a lot of change to your script, this should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)**. The following example shows you how to highlight a text entered inside a input dynamically inside a context with [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) (see demo below).

```js
var markInstance = new Mark(document.querySelector(".context"));
function highlight(){
    var searchTerm = document.querySelector("input").value;
    markInstance.unmark().mark(searchTerm);
}
```

```css
mark{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/julmot/mark.js/6.1.0/dist/mark.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Lorem ipsum..." oninput="highlight()">
<p class="context">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```